# How do you handle dynamic cookie buttons in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, facebook, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click the 'Allow essential and optional cookies button' which pops up on Facebook.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@id='u_0_e_EQ']")
button.click
```

the error is that the id (u_0_e_EQ) changes every time the page is reloaded. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: create xpath with button title or other unique tags

Comment: Add the 'HTML' source for the `element` you want to click.

Answer (score 2):

If the button label is unique, you can use it.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='button_label']").click
```